# How to call react props from a html page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am testing [this test React](https://github.com/khaledosman/react-redux-realworld-example-app) app and trying to call a prop from React into the Index.html that is located under the public folder of this repo.

What I want is to get the userName and edit the HTML to display something like below

```
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <li> The Current user is <INSERT PROPS HERE> </li>
  </body>
```

where the user props is located in a Header component located [here](https://github.com/khaledosman/react-redux-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/components/Header.js) as

`currentUser={this.props.currentUser}`

I am not even sure if this is possible as I am a newbie. I am assuming I might have to create a script to do this. Something like

```
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SOME LOGIC GOES HERE
    </script>
    <li> The Current user is <INSERT PROPS HERE> </li>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A React application in mounted into a specific HTML element usually the one with "root" id. Your project uses this pattern as well in this snippet:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>

), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any element outside the mounted element (div with root id) is not accessible by React.

Answer (score 0):

React is a library that fundamentally makes use of components based on jsx and parent-child props. You would be breaking the library's design purpose. If you want to edit and insert an html tag on a page you are viewing, it is better that you modify the react component that displays the data/ui where you want the change to be seen. If it is absolutely necessary, you can write a script but  it is recommended that you write it in a react component and depending on the component's life cycle component. You can read more about component lifecycle methods [here](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).